# Dont click on objects that are behind button

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have unity scene where located 4 cubes and button over them, this button is hidden and appears only when some event has happened. So when this button is not hidden I press it and objects that behind that button get clicked too, I dont want them to be clicked too, how can I make that only button will be clicked, nothing else? And question refered to previous one - can I make objects that belong to specified layer not interactable, so player will not be able to click them when I don't want him to?

Cube's clicks are catched by default method in MonoBehaviour -

```
void OnMouseDown() 
{
    Debug.Log("Cube clicked");
}
```

Button is created as built-in Unity UI object "Button" and when I click it launches some method that I choose, so all code which catches click on button was not written by myself, but by Unity creators

Here is photo of how my scene looks like[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add a code that shows how you detect Button click and you detect click on that object behind the Button. This will be useful in order to help you out. Don't include all your code, just piece of code that detects click or similar

Comment: Thahks for advise, did that

Comment: You only out code to detect object clicked. Where is the code you use to detect when Button is clicked?

Comment: @Programmer there is no code doing that, it's implemented like SP showed on screenshot, unity allows me to choose what method to launch when button is clicked, and catching click itself does unity engine

Answer (score 0):

Buttons usually don't work that way. Use button's `OnClick()` event to handle click action.

[image]

Add the script containing object in the `None(Object)` field and select a public method from next drowpdown field.

Comment: It was done that way, I think I had badly explained, but that is how I implemented button

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a [canvas group component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CanvasGroup.html) to the UI button. Then one of the options is to block raycasts, you should tick this and no mouse clicks will go through the UI element to the objects behind. (If I understood your problem correctly). Hope it helps.
[Canvas group component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRcXz.png)